# androidannotation with proguard

Tags: proguard, android-annotations

if I set the "minifyEnabled false" in proguard file on AndroidStudio IDE,It worked fine;But if I changed minifyEnabled true,it crashed when launched;The logs shows that some view throws nullpointerException;
Anybody knows why and how fix it?

Comment: You should paste the stacktrace of the exception. Without, it will be hard to help you.

Comment: proguard is probably stripping libs you're actually trying to use